# Must a program be 64-bits in order to get the speed benefit of having a x64 machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, chess

I'm planning on using a 64-bits bitboard to represent a chessboard in a basic chess playing program.

The program will run on a 64 bits machine, but will I be able to take advantage of all 64 bits if my program is not set up as a x64 program?

I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Comment: Your question is fairly incomprehensible. Of course, you can only run 64bit programs on a 64bit OS on a 64bit CPU, but that has absolutely nothing to do with your ability to make a chessboard.

Comment: Aaah! I reread my post after taking a nap, and I realize how confusing my question was. I meant to ask if I needed to specify my program as a 64 bit program in VS in order for me to get the speed benefit of having a x64 machine. However, I did a few tests, and found the answer to be yes.

Comment: That would be why that option exists :)

Comment: @Menjaraz: There is no need for titles to begin with "Asking..."; please do not add misspelled words in edit suggestions; I think the original was more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you need to compile your program as a 64 bits application if you want it to use the 64 bits registers and instructions that will make it much faster.

mp